# Get any html element clicked on using this and jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following code shows the text of any `p` element clicked on:

```
$("p").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

**But I'd like to generalize this and get the text of any html element clicked on**, not just `p`. I did the following but this returns the text of all html elements on the page:

```
$("*").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the [event's propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) so only the *clicked element* will raise this event and not all of its *containers* as well.

```
$("*").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

---

This is proabably more suitable:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/hMWgH/)

Comment: Why is the second snippet more suitable?

Comment: Because in this way you are actually attaching an event handler to only one element (the document), while in the first option you're attaching event handlers to all of your elements (which can be a lot like David has mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('*').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You clicked on `body` tag as you have included `*`

Try

```
$("*").click(function(e){
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
});
```

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)